# Send formdata in GET request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

i am doing a react project now and there is an api to fetch a list which is a GET request. In that request i have to pass parameters as formdata. Im using axios to make api calls. I tried the below code

```
   const formData = new FormData();
   formData.append("name", "john");

   return await API.get(
      "api/endpoint/getAllEmployees",
      formData
      // {
      //    headers: {
      //       "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
      //    },
      // }
   );
```

but when i look at the network tab,there is no formdata is sent with the request. Do anyone know how to send formdata in a get request using axios

Comment: axios({
                        method: "GET",
                        url: yourURL,
                        data: formData, 
                        header: {
                            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                        }
                    })

Answer (score 0):

actually, you can't do it ,ref to [rfc2616#](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.3),a get request can't carry a body with it, even you did it, the server will still ignore it.